AWS elastic beanstalk show a custom error page instead of 502 Bad Gateway
I want to show AWS a custom error page instead of 502 Bad Gateway when we have an issue with the APP, so far there are 2 solution I found:

Using a failover records with primary and secondary record to an S3 static website I don't see this as a practical solution as the DNS would be cached and even if the app is working again the user would still see the maintenance page unless he re-open his browser or something

Use CloudFront distribution in front of the endpoint: I see this as a better solution but we still can't use it as currently it's not possible t add CloudFront as we still have a lot oh HTTP request that takes more than 60 second and not sure if AWS could increase the limit to much higer than that like 30 min


So I am looking if there is a third solution that could include using lamda or maybe the laod balancer settings and rules or something
Thanks

Did you find a solution?

No nothing yet, I didn't find anything straight forward, most of the things I saw require a lot of settings and most likely it still wouldn't work so I didn't invest more time on this
